# How to change background color to transparent?

Tags: html, css, prestashop-1.7

I have [this website](https://157.245.179.75/?id_appagebuilder_profiles=8) in prestashop

And I want to change the background of the header to transparent.

The slider should appear in the background of the header like in this website `https://demotheme.site/prestashop/at_nova_demo/en/home-7.html`. I am trying to do that in inspect mode but I am not able to do it.

Comment: The link is invalid :(

Comment: can you try `background:transparent` ? could you please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the website should look like this: `https://demotheme.site/prestashop/at_nova_demo/en/home-7.html`

Comment: I think the problem @ `iviewSlider` class div. you add `background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/prestashop/at_nova_demo/themes/at_nova/assets/img/modules/leoslideshow/home7-slide1.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100%`

Comment: add `background-color:transparent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two css properties you need to change to make the header transparent:

when the page is not scrolled down:

```
#header.navbar-fixed-top {
   background: transparent;
}
```

when you scroll the page, also need to change this :

```
#header.navbar-fixed-top.mini-navbar {
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0); /* <----here set the opacity to 0 */
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O91LO.jpg)

to make slider appear in the background of the header, you need to remove the `margin-top` from `iviewSlider` element:

```
.page-index .iviewSlider {
    margin-top: 0; /* here set margin-top to 0, if not working, try to set as margin-top: 0 !important */
}
```

then your website will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOsG5.jpg)

Comment: Your answer is very close. But I want the slider to appear in the background of the header when not scrolled. Is it possible?

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar Sure it's possible, check my updated answer above.

Comment: Is it possible to make the slider 100vh?

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar Tried it, I could make slider 100vh, but somehow messed up the header position, might need more time to look into it, however even I forced the slider' height to be 100vh, the slider image's width and height would not fit my screen aspect ratio, you can try to use some other slider images who's width and height fit your screen, then the slider's height probably extends to fit the images in it thus to be 100vh.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Code**

```
header#header {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[inspector tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY09T.jpg)

follow this

-right click and inspect element
-use crome like browser and click the icon indicated in the image
-over the header and when is focused click it
-on the elements section of the browser console will be indicated the element and the class/id
-find the class/id in the css file and:

background:transparent;